# Looking for a YA Book series 70's or 80's

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm looking for the name of a Book series. The details of the books are as follows:

- It was about a young man who was the son of the emperor by a concubine.
- He was like 250th in line to the throne.
- There was some conspiracy against his father and an attempt to take over the empire.
- He traveled all the lands and the map looked a bit like the Mediterranean.
- In the end the emperor and his family are killed and the main character becomes emperor.
- I read it in the 80's.
- the whole series was maybe a half-dozen thin(ish) books - not Tolkien sized (or Jordan or Martin for sure),
- It was not for little kids; I was in my middle school library so about that level.

**What is the name of these series of books?**

Comment: What makes this question fantasy or science fiction?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't appear to contain any science fiction or fantasy elements

Answer (score -3):

I'm guessing this is Frank Herbert's *Dune* series, which matches all those points, except you seem to have missed the things that most people find memorable - Spice, sandworms, Bene Gesserit etc. It's not really YA either.

Comment: Really? You got Dune from that? What about "He travelled all the lands and the map looked a bit like the Mediterranean", sort of rules out Dune.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Well, I beg to differ. Paul *did* travel all around Arrakis - it's an essential part of the Campbellian Hero's Journey, which Herbert was conciously reflecting - and IMO the [Dune map](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Arrakis?file=L_Dune_Map.jpg) *does* look kind of like the Mediterranean, with the Shield Wall as the sea.

Comment: OK, I get where you're coming form now, it's been too long since I read Dune, and Lynch's movie has probably coloured my memories of the book. Apologies mate, I retract my previous statement.

Comment: The Dune books may be half a dozen (like Star Wars I don't count the prequels), but they are not thin(ish) books. Dune is 600 pages and even the thinnest, Dune Messiah, is more than 300 pages.